# Storing subImage data in an array

Tags: java, swing

So i have the following code:

```
package animation;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AnimTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    AnimTest test = new AnimTest();
    test.go();
}

public void go()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    MyDrawP drawP = new MyDrawP();
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawP);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

class MyDrawP extends JPanel
{

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    try {

        BufferedImage bigImg = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/scott/Desktop/Personal Work/Pixel Art/terrain.png"));

        final int width = 64;
        final int height = 64;
        final int rows = 5;
        final int cols = 16;
        BufferedImage[][] sprites = new BufferedImage[rows][cols];

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                sprites[i][j] = bigImg.getSubimage(i * width, j * height, width, height);
                //g.drawImage(sprites[i][j], 5, 5, this);
            }
        }
        //Image subImage = bigImg.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
        g.drawImage(sprites[0][0], 5, 5, this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Generating the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y +       height) is outside of Raster
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(Unknown Source)
at animation.MyDrawP.paintComponent(AnimTest.java:55)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Now, its saying something is wrong at line 55, but i dont understand why my code is generating that kind of an error; the RasterFormatException.

So what i would like to know is:

Is my code correct? Im trying to make a 2d array that stores subImages of my main image file into said array so i can recall them later at will based on their array positions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y +       height) is outside of Raster
```

Maybe you ran out of image dimensions? Look at [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: Thanks, i figured out what was going wrong. I had my variables backwards so that it was looking for a picture that was 320x1024 rather then my image, which is 1024x320.